# pod - How to kill or stop only one pod from n replicas of a deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a testing scenario to check if the API requests are being handled by another pod if one goes down. I know this is the default behaviour, but I want to stimulate the following scenario.

Pod replicas - 2 (pod A and B)

During my API requests, I want to kill/stop only pod A.
During downtime of A, requests should be handled by B.

I am aware that we can restart the deployment and also scale replicas to 0 and again to 2, but this won't work for me.

Is there any way to kill/stop/crash only pod A?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to `kubectl scale deployment ... --replicas=1` during the load test to kill one of the pods but not the other; you won't be able to control which it is, but you should still see all of the traffic go to the survivor.

Comment: Okay, not having control which I one to kill, that can be considered. Thanks! This gave me the answer I was looking for! @Da

Comment: @DavidMaze can you post this as answer with, will accept it? This explanation is really good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to simulate what happens if one of the pods just gets lost, you can scale down the deployment

```sh
kubectl scale deployment the-deployment-name --replicas=1
```

and Kubernetes will terminate all but one of the pods; you should almost immediately see all of the traffic going to the surviving pod.

But if instead you want to simulate what happens if one of the pods crashes and restarts, you can delete the pod

```sh
# kubectl scale deployment the-deployment-name --replicas=2
kubectl get pods
kubectl delete pod the-deployment-name-12345-f7h9j
```

Once the pod starts getting deleted, the Kubernetes Service should route all of the traffic to the surviving pod(s) (those with `Running` status).  However, the pod is managed by a ReplicaSet that wants there to be 2 replicas, so if one of the pods is deleted, the ReplicaSet will immediately create a new one.  This is similar to what would happen if the pod crashes and restarts (in this scenario you'd get the same pod and the same node, if you delete the pod it might come back in a different place).

Comment: Thanks! You explained both scenarios really well! This helped!

Comment: Thank you, the explanation of what each command simulates is helpful

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you can **manually** **kill** or **restart** the pod that is the only solution to test the case or else you can try crashing the one single POD but in the end, it will create the same scenario **POD** will auto restart.

Or else may you can increase the Graceful shutdown period for deployment so this way POD might take time and stay in terminating state for a good amount of time and you can perform the test.

Comment: (For purposes of this test, while one of the pods is restarting, the other(s) should be successfully handling the traffic, and it's also interesting to see if the recreated pod will correctly accept requests.  If the thing you're trying to simulate is "what happens if a pod crashes", Kubernetes will restart it on its own, so this approach will simulate that as well.)

Comment: @Harsh, I want the pod to be restarted again, that is not a problem, I just want the load to be transferred to another pod when first one is down. You answer gave me new learnings about graceful shutdown. Will check out that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In kubernetes where pods are controlled by the replicaSet, if you kill a pod it will again be recreated. So the only way to do this is to scale down the number of replicas.
Let's say if your deployment had 4 replicas. You can scale down to 3 by running the command below

```
kubectl scale deployment <deployment-name> --replicas=3
```

My example is as show below

```
kubectl scale  deployment hello-world --replicas=3
deployment.apps/hello-world scaled
```

Comment: Thanks @Baguma for prompt response. I understand the the pod will be created again, and I want it to be created again. Your suggestion too helped! Thanks.

Comment: @TechGirl I think for your case the Graceful shutdown is what may work as advised by David using the command below

***kubectl delete pod <pod-name>  --grace-period=60***

Where 60 indicates the number of seconds