# Stop one pod of a statefulset

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-statefulset

On my kubernetes (hosted on Azure), I have a Statefulset named `database` with a replica = 3 to handle my database cluster (so I have pods `database-0`, `database-1`, `database-2`)

I have some operations to perform on the disk of one of the 'cluster node'. I Would like to shutdown `database-1` (without stopping the two other pods), to be able to make changes to the disk mounted on a different pod, and then restart `database-1`.

How could I do that ? Is it even possible in kubernetes ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pod - How to kill or stop only one pod from n replicas of a deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68574484/pod-how-to-kill-or-stop-only-one-pod-from-n-replicas-of-a-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is no possible with statefulset controller. As the replica is 3 if you delete a specific pod, then the controller will bring back the pod. If you scale down the stateful set then the pods are terminated based on how much you scale down.